# make datepicker for dynamically inserted element not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, insertafter

I have a function for a button which is called on click event like this.Once clicked,a copy of element is inserted immediate after the row of the clicked button.I need to create date picker for an input field inside the newly inserted row.

```
<tr class="tr_38">
   <td>Maths [ Math01 ]</td>
   <td>Required</td>
   <td>
        <select style="width: 250px;" name="TeacherID[2318]" id="TeacherID[2318]">
        <option selected="" value="132">Dawn Herus - [ID : 132]</option>
        <option value="246">Margaret Wilson - [ID : 246]</option>
        </select>
   </td>
   <td>
        <input class="date hasDatepicker" id="ExamDate_2318" name="ExamDate[2318]" value="02/28/2017"  type="text">
        <input style="width: 100px;" id="ExamTime_2318" name="ExamTime[2318]" value="8:00" type="text">
   </td>
   <td><input value="+" class="more-38-0 more_button" type="button">
   </td>
  </tr>
```

Jquery function:

```
   `var counter = -1;
    $(document).on ('click','.more_button',function(){
        var courseID='';
        var row_classname =  $(this).closest('tr').prop('class');
        $.each($(this).prop('class').split(' '), function(i, name) {
            if (name.indexOf('more-') > -1) { // or name.indexOf('toaster') === 0
                courseID = name.split('-')[1];
                return false;
            }
        });
          var newrow = $('<tr class="'+row_classname+'"><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').text()+
          '</td><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(1)').text()+
          '</td><td>'+$(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(2)').html()+'</td><td>'+
          $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(3)').html()+'</td><td><input type="button" value="+" class="more-'+
          courseID+'-1 more_button"><input type="button" class="remove" value="X">'+
          '</td></tr>');
          var $newrow = $(newrow);
         $newrow.find('td:eq(2)').find('select').       prop('id','TeacherID['+counter+']').prop('name','TeacherID['+counter+']');
          $newrow.find('td:eq(3)').find('input[id^="ExamDate_"]').
      prop('id','ExamDate_'+counter).prop('name','ExamDate['+counter+']');

        $newrow.find('td:eq(3)').find('input[id^="ExamTime_"]').
       prop('id','ExamTime_'+counter).prop('name','ExamTime['+counter+']');
          $(newrow).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));


          **var $examdate = $('#ExamDate_'+counter);
          $examdate.datepicker();//this is not working** 

          $(this).hide();
          counter--;
    });`
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/r3qhokqn/7/)

Comment: which date picker you use in your fiddle haven't any external jquery added.

Comment: @BhupeshKushwaha Sorry I forgot to include .I am using normal jquery datepicker

Comment: it is Datepicker | jQuery UI

Comment: @BhupeshKushwaha yes

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the class from the dynamically entered datepicker and assign datepicker again to the same element.

```
$('#ExamDate_'+counter).removeClass('hasDatepicker').
        datepicker({ changeMonth: true,changeYear: true});
```